# 2 year old reverted to pee on floor

Tags: toddler, potty-training, diaper, urine

When our daughter was 2 years 1 month old she started asking to go to the toilet (she used to remove the diaper by herself and tell us she wants to go).

Up until now she did very well - very few misses and she has no problem doing no. 2 in the toilet.

She is very smart and speaks pretty well. She is 2 years 5 months now.

Last week she started holding her pees until she really had to go and then pee on the floor instead of telling us she needs to go. It happend almost every day since then.
Sometimes after peeing in the floor she said "look mom dad I peed"

We tried telling her many times that she needs to tell us when she has to go, but she doesn't do that any more. She just pees on the floor (chair, sofa, whatnot). She knows it's not "ok" but I'm not sure she understands that.

Today she peed on the floor 3 times already. We had to put the diaper back on.

We're helpless - how do we get her to stop doing that?

Note: it seems as she does not have this problem in the kindergarten as she goes and comes back with the same panties, but I suspect the teachers there "guide" the kids by actively taking them to the toilet. So no pee no misses

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have your answer.  Guide her!  She clearly already knows how to tell, she's just going through a phase - assuming there's no medical issue related to this, but it seems likely that would appear in the kindergarten as well if there were.  (But, always consider phoning your pediatrician when things like this change *just* in case.)

Set up a schedule, once an hour or whatever go give it a try.  Get her in that routine and she'll be over it soon, hopefully.

Comment: Agreed lots of guiding and minimal pressure would help. I bribed my daughter for a day or two with treats and that did the trick :)